# Dealing with a (possible) virus on both MacOSX and iOS

Tags: virus, macos, iphone

The symptom:

- On MacBookAir, in Safari, FF and Chrrome, when accessing www.google.com, I get redirected to a http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/ web page.
- On iPhone, when navigating to google.com  I get a Yahoo 404 -/ search error
- On iMac (from which I am posting this message), all seems to work ok

While I am scanning my MacBookAir with an antivirus (Sophos), I wonder, assuming it is infected, how would it also infect my iPhone?

**Update**
As time went by, the issue went away without me having to do anything. Meanwhile i scanned my MBA with Norton, AVG and Sophos - all 3 found no issues.

Comment: Do you sync your iPhone with your MacBook? If so, sync is a likely vector.

Comment: Does your iPhone also redirect, if it's not connected to WIFI?

Comment: This sounds more like a DNS issue then malware. The ultimate test is to wipe the iPhone and see what happens.  I can nearly guarantee that your iPhone isn't infected with malware.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you may have caught the `OSX.RSPlug.A Trojan` Look here for instructions on how to remove it: http://www.ehow.com/how_2128387_remove-osxrspluga-trojan-horse-mac.html

This trojan can only be obtained, by you actively downloading and installing it, probably masked as a trustworthy program.

As for antivirus, there's no AV Software out there, that will make sure that you can't obtain a virus. The best advice I can give you, is to use common sense when downloading, and try to verify the source. AV's tends to give people a false sense of security.

Comment: Thank you. I will go over this once i get home. See above, issue 'magically' went away. I went off the home wifi to the library wifi which (i don't have proof of this) may have cleared the issue for the iphone. I don't honestly remember if issue persisted while i was in the library.

Comment: If your iPhone starts acting weird, when it gets back on the WIFI, you should check your router, and see if it's been compromised, or any DNS rules have been added.

Answer (score 1):

If the phone and the mac book are independent of each other - then consider whether they are using the same source for internet connectivity - i.e. the same WiFi access point.

1. Try changing the access point DNS to that of [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/)